# Por que o getter retorna null?

Tags: java, android

No meu projeto de android studio eu tenho uma classe de getters and setters para me ajudar, mas por algum motivo na main activity quando chamo o `db.busca()` (que está na classe de operações da base de dados) que coloca um token no `u.setToken`("vem da BD").

Depois na MainActivity se eu der `user.getToken()` ele vem null, eu já tive a testar se eu der um `user.getToken()` na classe da Base de Dados funciona tudo ok, mas na MainActivity resulta null.

Em alguns casos eu quero que retorne null mas quando não devia retornar null e sim um token ele retorna null

Classe da Base de Dados:

```
    public void busca(){
    String[] colunas = new String[]{"token", "nome"};
    Cursor cursor = db.query("user", colunas, null, null, null, null, "token ASC");
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do{
            Utilizador u = new Utilizador();
            u.setToken(cursor.getString(0));
            u.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Classe Utilizador:

```
package imm.pt.immflix;

    public class Utilizador {
        private String nome;
        private String mail;
        private String token;
        private String foto;
        private int typeService;

        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }

        public String getMail() {
            return mail;
        }

        public void setMail(String mail) {
            this.mail = mail;
        }

        public String getToken() {
            return token;
        }

        public void setToken(String token) {
            this.token = token;
        }

        public String getFoto() {
            return foto;
        }

        public void setFoto(String foto) {
            this.foto = foto;
        }

        public int getTypeService() {
            return typeService;
        }

        public void setTypeService(int typeService) {
            this.typeService = typeService;
        }
    }
```

Classe MainActivity:

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
            TextView tvtitle = findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            ObjectAnimator anime = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tvtitle, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
            anime.setDuration(2000);
            anime.start();
            DB db = new DB(this);
            db.busca();
            Utilizador user = new Utilizador();
            token = user.getToken();
            if(token == null){
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
                        intent.putExtra("isNew", true);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }, 3000);
            }else{
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
                        intent.putExtra("isNew", false);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }, 3000);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `user.getToken()` está a ser usado logo após a instanciação do objecto `user`.

```
Utilizador user = new Utilizador();
token = user.getToken();
```

Como não foi atribuído nenhum valor ao campo `token` `user.getToken()` retorna nulo.

Com os elementos disponibilizado julgo que o método `busca()` deveria retornar um Utilizador para poder ser utilizado na classe Activity:

```
public Utilizador busca(){
    String[] colunas = new String[]{"token", "nome"};
    Cursor cursor = db.query("user", colunas, null, null, null, null, "token ASC");
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do{
            Utilizador u = new Utilizador();
            u.setToken(cursor.getString(0));
            u.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        return u;
    }
    return null;
}
```

O código na Activity deverá ser alterado para:

```
DB db = new DB(this);
Utilizador user = db.busca();
```

Já que há a possibilidade da query retornar nada, adicione um teste para verificar isso.

Não sei se a query poderá retornar mais de um Utilizador ou não, caso retorne, o método deverá retornar uma lista de Utilizador.

Não estive a ver se há mais alguma coisa "errada".

Comment: Obrigado, era esse o problema, e sim só retorno um "Utilizador" tecnicamente retorna um token e o nome do utilizador logado no meu APP e esse token depois é verificado com o servidor para efectuar outras acções, mais uma vez muito obrigado!